# Query to find all the empty tables in db2

Tags: db2-400

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = ISNULL(@sql + 'UNION ALL', '') + '
SELECT ''' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS col FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' HAVING COUNT(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') = 0
'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

EXEC (@SQL)

The above code works well in sql Server but doesnt work in db2. can somebody help me in this

Comment: What is the problem? Is there any error message?

Comment: Getting an error -199, sql state: 42601, Keyword nvarchar not expected.
Valid Tokens: Dynamic sensitive Asensitive Insensitive

Comment: Please include more info in your question.  Where are you trying to run this?  RPG, Java, other?

Comment: If you want a list of empty tables I'm not clear why you are looking at every column. Why not use COUNT(*) against each table just once? Alternatively on IBM i a DSPFD option gives you record counts, you could almost certainly run a single DSPFD to interrogate all tables, output to an outfile, and then use a simple SQL select statement on the output (can't do you the exact syntax as no access to an IBM i system right now).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess and say that your declaration is wrong. It's hard to say for sure without more info in the question but your declaration should probably look like so:

```
DECLARE @sql VARIABLE NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Comment: It says keyword variable not expected.
Valid Tokens: Dynamic sensistive Asensitive Insensitive

Comment: You still haven't told us where you are trying to run this which is why the above was just a guess.  Different interfaces can sometimes require different syntaxes.  See the following as an example: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzdclst.htm?view=kc